# Element not repeating on print with fixed position safari

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to display a logo at the bottom right of every print page but it isn't working on Safari (only displays on the first page). I did research and got it to work on Chrome with position fixed and it's working as intended by repeating on every print page. I'm not sure if it's because of the scrolling action on Chrome for print or what? Since Safari's print view isn't scrollable.

Here's what I have for the element I want to print. I am using Tailwind

```
<div className='print-logo hidden print:block print:fixed print:bottom-7 print:right-8'>
   <img src='/images/math-medic-logo.png' />
</div>
```

This is my css file. `page-break-after` on the body helped me with the other `position` safari issue I was having where it wouldn't allow me to use position `fixed` at all.

```
@media print {
  body {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}

@media print {
  div {
    break-inside: avoid !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
  span {
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
}
```

[This is the print view on Safari page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Md5p.png)

[This is the print view on Safari page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyJ2.png)

[This is print view Chrome page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHXu2.png)

[This is print view Chrome page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7uYe.png)